# Get Menu Name inside walker

Tags: menus, walker

I am trying to add some checkboxes to the menu editor in the WP admin area. I have successfully added them by creating an extension to the `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` class.

The checkbox is shown and it saves correctly. I would ideally only like to show the checkbox on a certain menu.

How can I get the name of the menu currently being edited inside the Walker.

Unfortunately `$post = null` so that doesn't work which was my first guess.

Comment: I understand. Can you post what you've got so far please? i.e. the class you're working with that extends the walker in core.

Comment: Edit your question to add also how you set your custom walker. Maybe with the filter `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker` ?